# OpenGL 3.3: GL_INVALID_OPERATION when calling glBindBuffer

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, opengl-3

Alright, so I am having a pretty tenacious issue setting up my OpenGL code. I'm trying to refactor my graphics code into a renderer object, but I can't seem to get to the bottom of a tricky GL_INVALID_OPERATION error (code 1282).

I start by creating a mesh object that initializes a loosely defined collection of OpenGL objects, and manages their lifespan in an attempt at RAII style:

```
struct OpenGLMesh
{
   OpenGLMesh(OpenGLRenderer& renderer, 
              int shader_index, 
              const char* fpath);

   ~OpenGLMesh();

   GLuint vbo_;
   GLuint ebo_;
   GLuint texture_;
   std::vector<float> vertices_;
   std::vector<unsigned int> indices_;
   GLuint shader_id_;
   GLuint mvp_id_;
};

OpenGLMesh::OpenGLMesh(OpenGLRenderer& renderer, int shader_index, const char* fpath)
{
   glGenBuffers(1, &vbo_);
   glGenBuffers(1, &ebo_);
   glGenTextures(1, &texture_);
   renderer.loadTexture(*this, fpath);

   const std::vector<GLuint>& shaders = renderer.getShaders();
   shader_id_ = shaders.at(shader_index);
   mvp_id_ = glGetUniformLocation(shader_id_, "MVP");
}

OpenGLMesh::~OpenGLMesh()
{
   glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo_);
   glDeleteBuffers(1, &ebo_);
   glDeleteTextures(1, &texture_);
}
```

At the same time I have a renderer object that owns the majority of the initialization and rendering functions. For example, the loadTexture function in the above constructor is part of the my OpenGLRenderer class:

```
OpenGLRenderer::OpenGLRenderer()
{
   glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao_); // allocate + assign a VAO to our handle
   shaders_.push_back(loadShaders("shaders/texture.vert", "shaders/texture.frag"));
}

OpenGLRenderer::~OpenGLRenderer()
{
   std::vector<GLuint>::iterator it;
   for (it = shaders_.begin(); it != shaders_.end(); ++it)
   {
      glDeleteProgram(*it);
   }
   glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao_);
}
```

My first concern is that compartmentalization of these function calls may have somehow invalidated some part of my OpenGL setup calls. However, the error doesn't make an appearance until I attempt to bind my mesh's VBO.

Below is the code from a stripped down test module I built to debug this issue:

```
// create the renderer object
OpenGLRenderer renderer;

// create and store a mesh object
std::vector<OpenGLMesh> meshes;
meshes.push_back(OpenGLMesh(renderer, 0, "./assets/dune_glitch.png"));

// SDL Event handling loop

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glBindVertexArray(vao_);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.vbo_);
printOpenGLError(); // prints out error code 1282
```

I've verified that it is definitely this line that breaks every time, although it doesn't seem to send a kill signal until the next iteration of the loop.

I haven't been able to find any insight on this problem - seems like glBindBuffer doesn't normally generate this kind of error. I've also made sure that the mesh.vbo_ ID still points to the same location.

For some reason, my application's stack trace doesn't play well with GDB, so I haven't been able to look at the trace as much as I would normally want to. Any advice would be a help, from debugging tips to possible sources of failure - thanks in advance!

(This is my first real post, let me know if I messed anything up!)

Comment: Related: [The rule of 3/5/0](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It the constructor of the calss `OpenGLMesh` the object buffers are generated (`glGenBuffers`). In the destructor `OpenGLMesh::~OpenGLMesh` the object buffers are destroyed (`glDeleteBuffers`).

In the following line:

```
meshes.push_back(OpenGLMesh(renderer, 0, "./assets/dune_glitch.png"));
```

you `push_back` the `OpenGLMesh` to a `std::vector`. This means that a temporary `OpenGLMesh` object is generated, an the object bffers are generated in its constructor. At this point all the data are valid and the object buffers are generated (GPU). When calling `std::vector::push_back`, then a new `OpenGLMesh` object is is generated, in the `std::vector`. The object is constructed by the default copy constructor and gets a copy of all the members of the first `OpenGLMesh` object. Immediately after this is done, the temporary `OpenGLMesh` object gets destroyed and the object buffers get deleted (`glDeleteBuffers`) by the destructor `OpenGLMesh::~OpenGLMesh` of the temporary object. At this point all the data are gone.

See [**`std::vector::push_back`**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/). Put a breakpoint in the destrutor `OpenGLMesh::~OpenGLMesh`, then you can simply track the expiration.

You should make the class **not** copyable and **not** copy constructable, but specify a move constructor and move operator.

```
class OpenGLMesh 
{
    OpenGLMesh(const OpenGLMesh &) = delete;
    OpenGLMesh & operator = (const OpenGLMesh &) = delete;

    OpenGLMesh( OpenGLMesh && );
    OpenGLMesh & operator = ( OpenGLMesh && );

    ....
};
```

You can quickly fix this behavior for debug reasons, by replacing

```
meshes.push_back(OpenGLMesh(renderer, 0, "./assets/dune_glitch.png"));
```

by

```
meshes.emplace_back(renderer, 0, "./assets/dune_glitch.png");
```

(see [`std::vector::emplace_back`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/emplace_back/))

For the implementation of a move constructor and move operator see:

- [Move assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment)
- [Move constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor)
- [C++11 Tutorial: Introducing the Move Constructor and the Move Assignment Operator](https://blog.smartbear.com/c-plus-plus/c11-tutorial-introducing-the-move-constructor-and-the-move-assignment-operator/)

Comment: Cool, this already got rid of the error at glBindBuffer. I'm going to accept this 'cause it fixed my immediate problem, but I also want to use this to attempt to fix my project code - do you mind if I check back? 

Also, just to confirm, this kind of deconstruction would also happen if I passed the Mesh obj as a parameter to a constructor?

Anyway, thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Cool, I'll check these out. I didn't know that the copy constructor called the destructor, but it makes sense. That was one of the few places I didn't check in my prior debugging 'cause I thought it was safe. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Just figured it out - it was a combination of this tip and an incorrect size parameter on my GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER data.